# Limit Subdomain Access on NGINX

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, subdomain

i have a domain, it's called `mydomain.com`, it's run on NGINX server.
i added new configuration on `sites-enabled` for `subdomain.mydomain.com`, and it's worked.

but when i access, `whatever.mydomain.com`, `wildcard.mydomain.com`, NGINX doesn't show 404, but it's execute configuration like `mydomain.com`.

how to limit access subdomain, only for available configration on sites-enabled ?

Comment: Please post relevant nginx conf, especially on `mydomain.com`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can setup a "catch all" server block like this:

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  server_name _;
  return 404; #alternative: return 444;
}
```

If you want to catch only subdomains to `mydomain.com`, you can specify `server_name *.mydomain.com` instead.

Generally, matching the server name is done by nginx in the following order:

1. exact match
2. longest match with * as prefix
3. longest match with * as suffix
4. first matching regex in the config
5. catch all block
6. first server block found in the config

Nginx could not find any match for your subdomain and therefore reached point 6 and used the only existing block.

More on the options for `server_name` can be found here: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html

Comment: this is the best solution what i've done